# Call public parent function from child class

Tags: c#, parent-child

Inside my `Main` method I'm instantiating the `UpdateDialog` class inside which based on if the user presses a button or not I need to call `function1()` from `Main`. Here is the code:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
  public void function1()
  {
    doing_stuff_here();
  }

  private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var update = new UpdateDialog();
    update.ShowDialog();
  } 
}

public partial class UpdateDialog : Form
{
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //call here function1() from Main
  }
}
```

What should I do to be able to call `function1()` from `Main` inside the partial class `UpdateDialog`?

LE: although the method suggested by Styxxy seems right it doesn't work well in my app because of `cross-thread invalid operation` so I ended up using the `delegate workaround` suggested by Cuong Le.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to have an instance of the `Main` form in your `UpdateDialog` form. As you say that UpdateDialog is a child form of your Main form, I guess that you create the UpdateDialog in your Main form and do a show there. Before showing that form, you could assign the [`Parent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx).

```
var updateDialog = new UpdateDialog();
// Or use "UpdateDialog updateDialog = new UpdateDialog();" as people like Andreas Johansson don't like the "var" keyword
// Do other stuff here as well
updateDialog.Parent = this;
// Or use Show() for non modal window
updateDialog.ShowDialog();
```

You get the error `ArgumentException: Top-level control cannot be added to a control.`. Now this can be solved in two ways.

1. You can set the [`TopLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel.aspx) property to `false` on your Main form (I'm not a huge fan of this).
2. You can use the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) property to your Main form (`this`). Below two ways of doing it.

You can set the `Owner` manually:

```
updateDialog.Owner = this;
```

Or you can add `this` as parameter to the [`Show(owner)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) or [`ShowDialog(owner)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) methods; this way, the `Owner` is also being set.

```
updateDialog.Show(this);
// or
updateDialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

"Full" code makes this:

```
var updateDialog = new UpdateDialog();
// Do other stuff here as well
updateDialog.Owner= this;
updateDialog.ShowDialog(); // or use .Show()
// or
updateDialog.ShowDialog(this); // or use .Show(this)
```

Comment: -1 for `var`. We know the type of the objects here. No point using `var`.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: Why we cannot use `var` in here?

Comment: Disagree. var is preferred **because** we can see what object is being instantiated. Declaring the type would be duplication.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson It was for code example only and to keep the code as short as possible. If you don't like the `var` word, don't use it... (it is not the point of this topic anyway). Downvoting because of this, is the same as downvoting because you prefix private fields of a class with `_` (or pick any other example)...

Comment: @Styxxy I tried the suggested sollution and I'm getting: `ArgumentException` occured : Top-level control cannot be added to a control. for `updateDialog.Parent = this;`

Comment: @Styxxy I tried using the Owner property as you suggested:           `var updateDialog = new UpdateDialog();
updateDialog.Owner = this;
updateDialog.ShowDialog();`     The problem is now I'm getting : `InvalidOperationExveption : Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Main' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Comment: I tested it with a few things (write something to the debug window, change the title of the Main form) and it all works. The error you have, is cause by something in your code that tries to do something cross-thread (in an invalid way). I suggest you open a new question, as it is something different (this answer aswers exactly what you ask for, and it works).

Comment: @CuongLe We **can** use it. But we **shouldn't**. The type `var` was designed for LINQ and in some projects (which I have the misfortune to often get into) it creates code ugliness of a higher degree. And one **should** declare the type of the variable that **is** going to be used. By the logic of GazTheDestroyer, we should use `Object` type, which in my opinion (shared by a number of people I've checked with) is less than optimal. But you're right that it works. So does my diploma work code too - doesn't mean it was good. :)

Comment: Using `Object` and `var` is entirely different. Please read the documentation again, because you really don't know what it exactly does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx And about the code ugliness: that is personal opinion, but my opinion is that putting twice the same type, only clutters the code. You're right about not using `var` in the situation `var i = 0;` I completely agree, but in **this** case, it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create an event in `UpdateDialog` then subscribe it after you create an instance inside the `Main` class. This way you have a better separation between these 2 classes.

```
public partial class Main
{
    public void function1()
    {
        doing_stuff_here();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var update = new UpdateDialog();
        update.OnButton2Click += OnUpdateDialogButton2Click;

        update.ShowDialog();
    }

    void OnUpdateDialogButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        function1();
    }
}

public partial class UpdateDialog
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnButton2Click;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call here function1() from Main  

        if (OnButton2Click != null)
        {
            this.OnButton2Click(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass `Main` class instance to your Update Form and store it in instance variable -

```
Main mainWindow = null;
public UpdateDialog(Main mainForm)
{
   mainWindow = mainForm;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mainWindow.function1();
}
```

And from Main method -

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var update = new UpdateDialog(this);
    update.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could turn it around, and let Main form listen to clicks from the UpdateDialog.

In Main:

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var update = new UpdateDialog();
    update.OnSomethingClicked += function1;
    update.ShowDialog();
} 

void form_OnSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do the stuff you want
}
```

In UpdateDialog:

```
public event EventHandler OnSomethingHappened;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     EventHandler handler = OnSomethingHappened;
     if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ShowDialog() method returns a DialogResult you can call function1 one of after the dialog is closed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can pass the Main class like a reference.

For example:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
     //make it internal, if UpdateDialog in the same assembly, and it only one that        would use it. In other words hide it for outside world.
     internal void function1()  
     {
         doing_stuff_here();
     }
 ....
}


public partial class UpdateDialog : Form        
{
      private MainForm _main = null;
      public UpdateDialog (MainForm main) { //Accept only MainForm type, _not_ just a Form
        _main = main;
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            _main.function1(); //CALL
      }
}
```

Something like this. You can change this accroding to your precise requirements, but this is a general idea.

Answer (score -1):

Approach #1

You need to create an instance of class `Main`.

```
Main foo = new Main();
foo.function1();
```

Approach #2

You need to declare the method as static.

```
public static function1(){ ... }
....
Main.function1();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make your function1 a Partial method and this way you can use it in all your partial classes.

Partial methods allow the definition of a method to be located in one file and the body of the method to be optionally defined in another file. They can only be used in partial classes and were introduced as language features in C# 3.0 and Visual Basic 9.0, the versions that shipped with the .NET Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

So what you can do is modify like this

```
public partial class Main : Form

        {
            public partial void function1()
            {
                doing_stuff_here();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var update = new UpdateDialog();
                update.ShowDialog();
            }   
        }

public partial class UpdateDialog : Form
        {
            public partial void function1();
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            function1();
            }
        }
```